# Unable to include plugins using vimrc . Error for each line of my vimrc

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, gvimrc

I have installed gVim and trying to have customizations, i.e, including plugins.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kinbiko/dotfiles/master/vimrc
Used multiple plugin managers, but in vain.

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\acer\_vimrc:

line    5:

E117: Unknown function: plug#begin

line    8:

E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim' "Nord 
theme

line    9:

E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace' 
"Mark trailing whitespace

line   13:

E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 
'NERDTreeToggle' } "File tree on the left hand side

line   14:

E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion' 
"Accurate navigation ala vimium

line   15:

E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'haya14busa/vim-asterisk' "Use * 
without moving immediately

line   19:

E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter' "Makes the git 
gutter with +, ~, and - available

line   20:

E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive' "Most git features 
available through :G*

line   21:

E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'rhysd/committia.vim' "git commit 
becomes magic

line   25:
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you load the plug-in manager itself?

Comment: yes, I did, in the autoload directory. @grawity

Comment: It looks like it can't find the plug.vim plugin manager, or it doesn't have a begin function.